# Array Formation - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am running an SQL Query in order to get the post IDs of the user currently logged in.

My query works as designed.

```
$userGadgets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT item_id FROM mg_gd_mylist WHERE user_id = '$user_id'", ARRAY_A);
```

The issue I am facing has to do with the array returned.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10318
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10378
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10566
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10608
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10614
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10648
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10292
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10274
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10306
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 9312
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10652
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10324
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10342
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10696
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10672
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 10372
        )

)
```

The model I am trying to produce is the following

```
Array
(
    [0]  => 140 //The item_id string as an integer


    [1] => 141


    [2] => 142

)
```

Any ideas on that one ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but do You want to convert that string to int?
If so, you can use (int) $example , where $example is your string. Now you can use it as an integer.

Comment: your array format is not good so just

use this code 

echo "<pre>":
print_r($yourarray);

then update question

Comment: first of all who upvoted and marked as a favorite question to this type of question ?

Comment: `array_map('intval', array_column($array, 'item_id'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code , guess you want to single array result

check `array_reduce ()` built in function

```
<?php
$your_array = array(0 => array('item_id' => 3160), 1 => array('item_id' => 13123), 2 => array('item_id' => 234234), 3 => array('item_id' => 2123));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_array);
$convert_array = array_map('intval', array_column($your_array, 'item_id'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($convert_array);
```

then your original Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3160
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 13123
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 234234
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2123
        )

)
```

and output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3160
    [1] => 13123
    [2] => 234234
    [3] => 2123
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would that be a bad output?

Simply use:

```
array = [];
foreach($arrayReturned as $i=>$row){
   // you get every data with $row['item_id'], for example
   array[] = $row['item_id'];
}
```